# Core prepreg strategy for amplifier with feedback

Tags: pcb

I have built a circuit which is an amplifier working from 0 to 5 MHz, so there is there is  feedback issue which I though to implement using a via which will connect the plus of the opamp with the feedback loop.

For me prepreg and core are layer of a single cake(PCB). Basicly I want gnd->dielectric->signal-->dielectric->signal.

I know that we need to manufacture this PCB using ready cores which are plated from both sides and prepreg is like a glue.

So if I take 2 cores(covered with copper from both sides) and glue them together using PREPREG then I get 4 metal layers where as I need only 3? What could be done the get a 3 metal sheet PCB?

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a really good reason to want exactly 3 layers? If so, contact many different manufacturers, and you might end up with one able to do it for your. But this will probably be some custom design and process, that will end up being very expensive.

The practical solution would be to use a standard 4 layers PCB (copper - prepreg - copper - core - copper - prepreg - copper)

If you really just want not to use one of the layers, you can make it :

1. GND
2. GND
3. signal
4. signal

But you might as well make use of this "free" extra layer. There are many options (I'm not able to tell you which one is the best) :

Option 1 : reduce signal crosstalk :

1. GND
2. signal
3. GND
4. signal

Option 2 : improved shielding from external noise, reduced radiated noise :

1. GND
2. signal
3. signal
4. GND (with very short tracks just to connect vias to compents)

Option 3 : supply plane :

1. Power
2. GND
3. signal
4. signal
   or probably better :
5. Power
6. signal
7. GND
8. signal

And many more combinations.

So basically there is a good reason why there are no PCBs with odd numbers of layers : they are more costly to produce than just adding one extra layer, and this extra layer usually has no downside (worst case : get all the copper removed), and usually even small benefits.

Conclusion : just use a 4 layers PCB, excepted if you are an expert with very specific requirements.

Comment: Hello Sandro ,Ok i understand.i will use 4 layer PCB as shown in the photo below.the first layer will be the place for the OPAMPS and capacitors and resistors.then i put VIA from metal layer 1 to metal  layer 2 so the signal will go from output to M2 and from M2 to the PLUS of the OPAMP.
Metal layer 4 will be the GND,so i will make one VIA from M1 to M4 as shown in the last photo.we have one last  M3 which is not used,So you say i can use it to route the power supplying of my OPAMPS? Thanks.
https://ibb.co/DWH1vyr
https://ibb.co/0DBzdMP
https://ibb.co/bLfY7tT
https://ibb.co/0XwPFwW